# Syntax - R Data Frames

Tags: r, dataframe, syntax

I have a data frame df.

30 columns, about 1.5m rows.

I want to "normalise" columns 13 to 30 by dividing each number in those columns by the mean for that column. I can do this:

```
df_norm[, 13] <- df[, 13] / Column_Means[1]
df_norm[, 14] <- df[, 14] / Column_Means[2]
df_norm[, 15] <- df[, 15] / Column_Means[3]
...etc...etc...etc..
df_norm[, 29] <- df[, 29] / Column_Means[17]
df_norm[, 30] <- df[, 30] / Column_Means[18]
```

And it works, but it's clumsy and a bit slow. I had hoped to do it all in one line,  perhaps something like:

```
df_norm[, 13:30] <- df[, 13:30] / Column_Means
```

or

```
df_norm[, 13:30] <- df[, 13:30] / Column_Means[1:18]
```

but this doesn't seem to work - it always divides by Column_Means[1] instead of going through all 18 values.

Please can someone tell me if there's a single line of code that will do what I need? I like to write concise code if I can, but I'm a bit of a novice with R's syntax.

Many thanks...

Comment: `df_norm[,13:30]<-lapply(df[,13:30],function(x) x/mean(x))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using the dataframe mtcars available in R. Let's load it into a new dataframe so we can modify it later:

```
df_cars <- mtcars
```

Now, suppose you want to "normalize" the first two columns:

```
df_cars[ , c(1:2)] <- df_cars[ , c(1:2)]/colMeans(df_cars)[c(1:2)]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. Yes, a bit more compact!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` or `lapply` and make your function inside

```
apply(df[,13:30],2, function(x) x/mean(x))
lapply(df[,13:30], function(x) x/mean(x))
```

Like @Roland says, is better to use `lapply` to loop over data.frame columns.

Comment: You shouldn't use `apply`. Use `lapply` to loop over data.frame columns.